# How to find the currently active item in tab bar using squish where the AUT is a Qt application

Tags: qt, tcl, tabbar, squish

I am using squish to test one qt application.My requirement here is to find the active item in a tab bar. Can some body share the code which is written in tcl code to find the active item in the tab bar

Comment: You have to find tab widget object and that call `currentIndex()` function to get the active tab's index.

Comment: @vahancho it worked.Got it by looking for the currentIndex property of TabWidget.